# angular - directive on an element under ng-if not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with tabs, here's an example of one of them:

```
<li ng-if="userData.isMaster">
 <a data-target="#debug-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-name="debug" on-tab-shown>Debug</a>
</li>
```

This tab is similar to other tabs, with the exception that it is under ng-if. Each tab has an "on-tab-shown" directive which broadcasts an event each time the tab is shown. Inside each tab's controller there's an event listener that listens to this event. In other tabs, that are not under ng-if, the event is received by the listeners, but not in this tab. It is possible to replace the ng-if with ng-show to make it work, but are there better ways maybe?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid ng-show?

Comment: First reason is so that the tab's controller won't be instantiated if not necessary, and the other, well I'm not sure...But isn't ng-if more secure than ng-show?

Comment: Dont need to worry too much about the performance problem that you will have by instantiate a new controller. In my own experience, I have a label directive that is used more than 50 times, with other directives and controllers. The page has no performance issue at all. To your 2nd reason, no there is no security benefits. I mean there is no security on the client side at all. Such as we can change lots of stuff in console :D.

Answer (score 1):

If your [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) is set to not show the tab (`userData.isMaster == false`), then the tab is removed from the DOM.  Since it isn't on the DOM, it won't react to the broadcast.  If you need it to react to the broadcast even though it isn't showing, you will need to use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) so it is simply hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid no. The thing is, that ng-if completely blocks the linking of the element it's put on and all its children (in fact, they're even removed from the DOM). That's why ng-show works, because ng-show does not block any linking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to favor ng-show if it works better. All you're doing is adding to the DOM, or not. Per Angular's documentation:

> ngIf differs from ngShow and ngHide in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property.

Here's the link if you'd like more info -- good luck!!

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf